# OpenSource Monitoring & Job Scheduling Framework

Tags: java, monitoring, scheduled-tasks, alerts

I'm looking for a framework that can handle starting and stopping processes on linux hosts as well as monitoring a given processes life cycle.

More specifically I want to be able to do things like below across a fleet of hosts

- schedule a process to always be running and be notified if it isn't (mysql, activemq etc..)
- schedule a script or process to run at a specific time
- schedule a process to be stopped and started at specific times
- have monitoring and alerting notify me if a process on a host isn't running when it should be
- the start and stop commands as well as other meta info about a given job would need to be totally customizable
- an added bonus would be if could do alerting at the host level of things like disk full, high memory or CPU usage

I've got a number of different types of scripts and services this would be used for (java, ruby etc...), is anyone aware of something like this out there?

Comment: The [Open Source Job Scheduler](http://jobscheduler.sourceforge.net/osource_scheduler_features_en.htm) may be what you're after.

Comment: I'll take a look at this and see what it has to offer, I also have heard of JAMS, http://www.jamsscheduler.com, but it isn't free.

Comment: @JeremyT Did it work out for you? It would be useful for others to know.

Comment: I'm still looking into it, it takes a bit of setup time and I haven't had a chance to get it running yet. I'll update this once I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read about [zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/product.php) or [nagios](http://www.nagios.org/). both are great for performing this kind of staff.

> With Nagios you can:

- Monitor your entire IT infrastructure
- Spot problems before they occur
- Know immediately when problems arise
- Share availability data with stakeholders
- Detect security breaches
- Plan and budget for IT upgrades   •Reduce downtime and
  business losses

> Below is a short list of features available in Zabbix:

- auto-discovery of servers and network devices
- low-level discovery distributed monitoring with centralized web administration support for both polling and trapping mechanisms
- server software for Linux, Solaris, HP-UX, AIX, Free BSD, Open BSD, OS X
- native high performance agents (client software for Linux, Solaris, HP-UX, AIX, FreeBSD, OpenBSD, OS X, Tru64/OSF1, Windows NT4.0, Windows 2000, Windows 2003, Windows XP, Windows Vista)
- agent-less monitoring
- secure user authentication
- flexible user permissions
- web-based interface
- flexible e-mail notification of predefined events
- high-level (business) view of monitored resources
- audit log

Answer (score 0):

We do use JAMS at my company and it works well.  Was not cheap (I was not involved in the $ negotiations) but I did evaluate it and liked it a lot. The PowerShell Provider is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

JobServer is one option. It allows running any arbitrary unix/linux batch script or java/python/ruby type program. You can turn any script or program into a job without a lot of work via GUI. Also has a lot of GUI management tools for monitoring/tracking/reporting...etc.

Answer (score 0):

there is a community edition to JAMS that you can download.  Only allows for executing 50 jobs/day but it does a nice job

Answer (score -2):

I also found this framework which looks pretty solid http://sna-projects.com/azkaban/